# Stored Procedure to comapre 2 fields and return mismactch in another table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am creating  stored procedure in Oracle SQL Developer. I am trying to compare two columns form 2 tables and if any table has more records , I need to collect them  and store it in ( another table) my  stored procedure  works fine if I have  only one recorded mismatch, anything over one record and it throws

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "TEST_VAL", line 73
ORA-06512: at line 2

here is the query that run just fine  if I run it as SQL query

```
SELECT h.STATEMENTNUMBER, h.STATEMENTTOTAL
FROM statement_header h
MINUS
SELECT j.STATEMENTNUMBER, j.STATEMENTTOTAL
FROM jwf_statement j;
```

and my stored procedure looks like this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE        TEST_VAL 
IS
l_num_recs        VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
select STATEMENTNUMBER into  l_num_recs
from
(SELECT H.STATEMENTNUMBER, H.STATEMENTTOTAL
FROM statement_header H
MINUS
SELECT J.STATEMENTNUMBER, J.STATEMENTTOTAL
FROM jwf_statement J

);
insert into l_num_recs values(l_num_recs);
Commit;
End;
```

any help is appriciated

Comment: Would you please add a question at the end of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE        TEST_VAL 
IS
BEGIN
insert into destinationTableName
select STATEMENTNUMBER
from
(SELECT H.STATEMENTNUMBER, H.STATEMENTTOTAL
FROM erocks.statement_header_staging H
MINUS
SELECT J.STATEMENTNUMBER, J.STATEMENTTOTAL
FROM erocks.ps_jwf_statement_staging J
);
Commit;
End;
```